# Why are there grey blocks of color on the VS Code editor window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VS Code editor window, there are squares of another color that bother me when coding.

Has anyone had or has the same problem?

[image: screenshot of VS Code]

Comment: Try Reinstalling, That might help.

Comment: I've never seen that. Maybe try restarting vs code (or your computer)? If that doesn't work @Haris is probably right and you should reinstall it.

Answer (score 10):

I started experiencing this issue in my MacBook Pro M1 after the June 2022 autoupdate.

Setting `"disable-color-correct-rendering": false` in  `~/.vscode/argv.json` worked for me.

I hope this is fixed in the next release. It seems to be an old issue based on what I found when searching for a solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a mac, see [Different colored area on macOS](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152816) - although there is a linux report there too.  Same dark grey patches of color.  There are a couple of suggested fixes mentioned.

The most reliable appears to be changing this setting:
`"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`

> 1. Open command palette and search for "Configure Runtime Arguments"
> 2. Set "disable-hardware-acceleration": true
> 3. Restart

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156405#issuecomment-1196503399

or starting vscode from a terminal with `code  --disable-gpu`.

Also

> What did work is removing `"disable-color-correct-rendering": true` from
> `~/.vscode/argv.json` file and restarting vscode. Now the different
> coloured patch on the side and bottom is gone.

Or

> This happens to me with an intel mac as well. It was fixed by setting
> `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true` in the `.vscode/argv.json` file.

More from the issue:

> Had the same problem on my M1 macbook air, I had to open the argv.json
> file (you can use Shift + CMD + P and type `Configure Runtime Arguments`
> to open it) and set this line to `false` :
>
> `"disable-color-correct-rendering": false` (it was on `true`, maybe by
> default).
>
> After that, just close your VS Code instance with CMD + Q and restart
> it.

And here are download links (for macOS) for the previous vscode version v1.68 in case you want to rollback:

```
https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f//VSCode-darwin-universal.zip
https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f/VSCode-darwin.zip
https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/4af164ea3a06f701fe3e89a2bcbb421d2026b68f/VSCode-darwin-arm64.zip
```

Thanks for the information to those posting in the issue comments.

Comment: Removing "disable-color-correct-rendering": true from ~/.vscode/argv.json resolved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this on mac you have to follow following steps

1. open terminal and type `cd ~/.vscode`
2. then open 'argv.json' file using `vim argv.json`

just uncomment the line `// "disable-hardware-acceleration": true` to `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`

quit vim `Esc` then `shift+:` then `wq` then press enter, restart vs code your vs code will work normal again.