# Problem with blocked-empty space in editor area

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed yesterday, that my vscode editor has empty-blocked space in bottom area on editor.

Bellow screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgFPM.gif

I remove all plugins, restart setting and still have this problem.
Anyone have idea, how I can fix it?

My version os vscode:

```
Version: 1.69.0 (Universal)

Commit: 92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9

Date: 2022-07-07T05:28:41.511Z (2 days ago)

Electron: 18.3.5

Chromium: 100.0.4896.160

Node.js: 16.13.2

V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0

OS: Darwin arm64 21.4.0

&#x200B;
```

Comment: have you tried to `disable graphics acceleration`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72916668/9938317

Comment: @rioV8 'disable graphics acceleration' not working on 
MacBook 16 M1. Anyone ideas?