# Having this weird bug with visual studio code on Mac. Its showing an highlight

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

Can I get some help in fixing this bug please with VS code. Its highlighting or showing a weird color while coding. Anyone know what settings will fix this. I tried deleting and reinstalling vs code but same thing

[image]

Comment: I think this question belong to supersuser website

Comment: there are a lot of bugs in the last update of vs code, for example in HTML we can't do anymore `!` to have the HTML boilerplate. I think Microsoft will solve this in the next update

Comment: Duplicate with possible fixes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72918752/836330