# How to change the weird light color block in VS Code editor area

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Actually I don't know when it existed, but recently after changing some themes, the editing area has a strange light color block.

It's neither a blank string nor a blank line break, it 'jumps' with the area you're editing. This is quite annoying and I have not been able to find a real answer to this problem.

In some cases, changing the theme occasionally helps, but it mostly doesn't work, and I don't think that's a good idea because those light blocks are always stubbornly present, can anyone help?

P.S I hope I can express the problem precisely enough, I'm attaching a screenshot to point out the so-called 'light blocks'.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the minimap? From your menu bar, View > (uncheck) Show Minimap

Comment: @StephenTaylor I have confirmed that, unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: It's a trap!  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916668/why-are-there-grey-blocks-of-color-on-the-vs-code-editor-window

Comment: @Mark Haha, someone really came across this problem, it's really weird right? thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

After some time of research, I have to think that this seems to be the only solution for now. Originally I used developer tools in an attempt to change the CSS, but decided that was an illegal hacking solution, and I thought the app could be overwritten if I updated it, so I abandoned that idea.

Now I found a possible solution.

Go into settings, search for: @id:workbench.colorCustomizations workbench

Note: You must choose to also modify on User, otherwise it will only work on the current window workspace.

After entering setting.json, look for Workbench: Color Customizations and add editor.background to workbench.colorCustomizations, example:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "editor.background": "#19485964"
},
```

The most important point is that transparency must be set! As long as editor.background is set to a certain level of transparency, then the "strange light color blocks" will disappear.

Although I'm not sure if this is a real solution, it can solve the problem to some extent, and no failure has been found yet, so I assume this is "barely a solution" for now.

If there is a better answer, I would welcome any additional information, thank you.