# VS Code is changing parts of the background color when clicking around

Tags: visual-studio-code

What are these rectangles on the right and bellow the code? When I click on a different line the rectangles move. Can I turn it off?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
What could be the reason for these changes in the background color? It happens with every VSCode theme. Does it have to do with line length?

[image]

Comment: There was a very similar question here a few days ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72989807/how-to-change-the-weird-light-color-block-in-vs-code-editor-area

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the weird light color block in VS Code editor area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72989807/how-to-change-the-weird-light-color-block-in-vs-code-editor-area)

Comment: Thank you Dorian. It doesn't provide an answer though.

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed with

`Shift + CMD + P` and type Configure Runtime Arguments

```
"disable-color-correct-rendering": false
```

More info here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152816