# VS Code main Layout uneven background

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been facing this weird issue in my VS Code.
The background is not even across the board. What can I do to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.
mac OS 12.4
[image]

Comment: Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916668/why-are-there-grey-blocks-of-color-on-the-vs-code-editor-window

Answer (score 2):

Removing "disable-color-correct-rendering": true from ~/.vscode/argv.json resolved my issue