# Vs Code - How can I set the line width

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS code insider but somehow the each line width is small. Please check this image:

[image]

In this image you can see that each code is breaking to next line due to the width of main wrapper.

How can I make it full width or auto?

Comment: If you're talking about just how many characters can fit on a line before it breaks to the next then you just need to setup a formatter. I use [prettier](https://prettier.io/) and define a print-width property in a config file.

Comment: @AWebb okay. let me try with this.

Comment: you can install as a VS Code extension. Then create a `.prettierrc` file in the root directory and paste this into it - `{
  "printWidth": 100
}`

Comment: I have created the file in the project directory and add that code but still same.

Comment: Are you on a mac?  It looks like the lines break at the discolored region to the right.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916668/why-are-there-grey-blocks-of-color-on-the-vs-code-editor-window - that might be helpful.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I using Mac.